# clicking all the buttons on a page with a given interval

Tags: jquery

I have this page that displays a list of buttons, a hundred at least at a time, I would like some jQuery code that clicks all these buttons one by one with a five 3 second interval for example, below is the Query I wrote, but it only clicks like 3 to four buttons then it cuts off

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".generate_all").click(function(e){
        var generateButtons = $('.generate');
        var numberOfButtons = generateButtons.length;

        for(var i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++){
            generateButtons[i].click();
        }       
    })
});
```

Comment: 'with a five 3 second interval' ...?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you could loop through the buttons attaching a timeout to each which triggers its own `click` event handler. You can offset these timeouts by multiplying the delay by the index of the element, something like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).index());
}).each(function(i) {
  (function(el, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(el).click();
    }, 3000 * (index + 1));
  })(this, i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>0</button>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</div>
```

Note the IIFE expression within the `each()` handler. This is required to maintain scope of the `button` to be clicked when the delay finally executes.

Also note that this uses a 3 second interval (the `3000` value), but that can be easily change to 5 seconds if required, as your question wasn't clear in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code,

`for(var i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++){
            generateButtons[i].click();
        }`

write instead that loop, something with timeout, something like:

```
generateButtons.each(function(i) {
  (function(item, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(item).click();
    }, 3000 * (index + 1));
  })(this, i);
```